# slave lost and very slow join in spark

Tags: performance, join, apache-spark, slave

I did a join of two dataframes on one common column and then ran a show method:

```
    df= df1.join(df2, df1.col1== df2.col2, 'inner')
    df.show()
```

Then join ran very slow and finally raise an error: slave lost.

```
    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o109.showString.

    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 8.0 : ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Slave lost
```

Driver stacktrace:
         at

> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2086)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1498)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1505)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1375)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1374)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2099)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1374)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1456)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:170)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

After some search, it seems this is a memory related issue. Then I increased repartition to 3000, increased executor memory,increased memoryOverhead, but still no luck, I got the same  slave lost error.  During  df.show(), I found one of the execuctor shuffle write size is very high, the others were not so high.
Any clue?
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the data might be skewed - how many rows are in the two data frames respectively? Also what sort of instance types are you running on and how much memory do you allocate? And can you try to do a `count` instead of a `show` after the `join`?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt     Yes the count went through. One dataframe  is 100 times bigger than another one. The smaller df is around 6M. I'm using Spark 1.6 on EC2.

Comment: I suspected so. I'm guessing that if you do a `df= df1.join(df2, df1.col1== df2.col2, 'inner').persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)` followed by a `df.count` followed by a `df.show`, it probably goes through as well, right?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt  haven't try that yet.  but why count went through and show did not? Is there any preprocessing for a better join?

Comment: Well, I have not verified this, but I suspect that since `show` will need to collect data to the driver, it's probably collecting to a single partition. Now, as I'm sure you know, Spark splits processing into stages, but the number of partitions used in each stage seems to be defined by  the number of partitions required at the stage boundary. So if you for instance read in a file, do a bunch of maps and filters (that won't trigger a stage boundary) and then write it back to disc in a single file, all you see that your map and filter operations will in fact be processed in a single partition.

Comment: This is why I suggest triggering the evaluation with a count instead. `count` will force parallel evaluation of your join and as long as you persist the result, the following `show`(which then simply collects data) will be super fast

Comment: I actually have it on my ToDo to post exactly this problem here on SO, as I have done some test which (to my great frustration) illustrates that calling persist and count will in certain scenarios speed up processing greatly.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt I switched to Spark2 and all these issues are gone. It seems Spark 2 might have a  better optimization than Spark1.6.

Comment: Thank you for your in depth answer.

Answer (score 1):

If using scala try

```
val df = df1.join(df2,Seq("column name"))
```

if pyspark

```
df = df1.join(df2,["columnname"])
```

or

```
df = df1.join(df2,df1.columnname == df2.columnname)
display(df)
```

If trying to do same in pyspark - sql

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("left_test_table")
df2..createOrReplaceTempView("right_test_table")
left <- sql(sqlContext, "SELECT * FROM left_test_table")
right <- sql(sqlContext, "SELECT * FROM right_test_table")

head(drop(join(left, right), left$name))
```